# Verb to mean a place is getting to your head

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I seem to remember the existence of a phrasal verb to mean that a place is getting to your head, i.e. the place is starting to influence your choices and/or changing your persona. I though "it grows on you" could work but apparently it means something completely different.

Some examples:

1.

> In *The Shining* Jack Torrance is first portrayed as a normal family man, but the more time he spends in the house the more the place starts to X (on) him.

2.

> Everyone moving from a tropical country to a Nordic country reports how the lack of light can truly effect one's perception of the world. The greyness of the sky can quickly [X] (on) you, which goes a long way explaining the high rates of suicide among expatriates.

Any suggestion is welcomed!

Comment: "Imprint" Perhaps. Or in certain contexts, possibly you could use "Consume", or "Devour".

Comment: Is it places only, or could other things [X] (on) you too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a single word, but for negative/harmful impacts (like both of your examples seem to be) you could use “[do a number on you/your head](https://books.google.com/books?id=kXDHJm0x1PgC&pg=PA27&dq=%22can+really+do+a+number+on+your+head%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi95b302q7LAhVNyGMKHYAtDMUQ6AEINjAF#v=onepage&q=%22can%20really%20do%20a%20number%20on%20your%20head%22&f=false)”:

> [T]his town can really do a number on your head.

(example of it used with a place from ‘Gillette: A Play’ by William Hauptman, via ‘Google Books’)

> “[Number, do
>   a](http://www.word-detective.com/2010/07/number-to-do-a/)” (from ‘The
>   Word Detective’):
>
> “[T]o do a number on” … first appeared in the African-American
>   community in the late 1960s meaning “to act with destructive impact
>   on” … [but] has been tempered somewhat as its use became more
>   mainstream, and it’s often now used to mean simply “affect negatively”
>   (“Frigid temperatures can do a number on your plumbing if your pipes
>   aren’t properly insulated,” 2010).

For a single word to use with “on,” there’s “[play on](https://books.google.com/books?id=nRuGqYW_v5cC&pg=PA216&dq=%22plays+on+his+mind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwiK-i5a7LAhVEmYMKHQRBDi0Q6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%22plays%20on%20his%20mind%22&f=false)/upon [his/your mind]” in the sense of having an effect on something:

> [play on something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+on):
>   **to have an effect on something**; to manage something for a desired
>   effect. (The on can be replaced by upon.)

(example of usage of “plays on his mind” from ‘The Dave Bliss Quintet: An Inspector Bliss Mystery’ by James Hawkins, via ‘Google Books’ and a definition of it from ‘McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs’ via ‘The Free dictionary by Farlex’)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest,

[***rub off on you***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22place+rubs+off+on%22&biw=549&bih=360&prmd=ismvn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq75zAsq7LAhWMExoKHUisAXQQ_AUICygG)

> rub off (on someone)
>
> Become transferred to another, influence through close contact. This idiom alludes to transferring something like paint to another substance by rubbing against it. [Mid-1900s] (The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer)
>
> [FOD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rub+off+on)
>
> =  influence, affect, be transferred to, be passed on to, have an effect on, be transmitted to.
>
> [CED](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/rub-off-on-someone)

***impact (on) you***

> impact (*tr.*/*intr.*): to have a strong and often bad effect (on)
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impact)

[***creep up on you***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=562&bih=369&noj=1&tbm=bks&q=%22quickly+crept+up+on%22&oq=%22quickly+crept+up+on%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...4087.9926.0.10557.14.14.0.0.0.0.339.1910.0j2j5j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..6.6.1338.KSJ9jCiSW_c)

> creep up on someone
>
> If a ​feeling or ​state ​[creeps up on you](https://www.google.fr/search?biw=1024&bih=672&noj=1&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=VJvdVt2WNMiLU8WuvfgE&q=creeping+vines&oq=creeping+vin&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.1.0.0i19l3j0i30i19l2.7188.14129.0.18151.28.22.0.2.2.0.1266.6835.0j7j4j2j0j1j0j3.17.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..17.11.2434.3.EF61bFtrW3A), you ​start to ​experience it so ​gradually that you do not ​realize it.
>
> [COD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/creep-up-on-sb)

Answer (score 3):

I would say "get to you", although this implies a negative effect.  In fact, i would say "get to you" for a negative effect and "grows on you" for a positive effect.

*"This town is really getting to me."* means "I'm beginning to really dislike it."

*"This town is really growing on me."* means "I'm beginning to really like it."

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest two phrasal verbs that could work here:

> [Take hold of you](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/take-hold-of)
>
> 1. to take; seize; grasp
> 2. to get control or possession of

In The Shining Jack Torrance is first portrayed as a normal family man, but the more time he spends in the house the more the place starts to take hold of him.

> [Take root within you](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/take-root)
>
> 1. to begin growing by putting out roots
> 2. to become settled or established

Everyone moving from a tropical country to a Nordic country reports how the lack of light can truly effect one's perception of the world. The greyness of the sky can quickly take root within you, which goes a long way explaining the high rates of suicide among expatriates.